# Button click not excuting sql query

Tags: c#, sql, button, webforms

Im developping a small website to help a local gym I go to.

Im able to list all of the invoices for a specific customer and add a button to confirm that an invoice has been paid

However when i press that button the sql query in code behind is not being executed. I suspect its because the page is reloading everytime I click on that button but im not sure.
Also if i only have one customer in the dropdownlist its working fine, so i know that the problem is not the sql query

[image]

```
                //Ajout Bouton Modifier/Ajouter
                Button bouton = new Button();
                bouton.ID = "bouton" + i.ToString();
                TableCell ajoutbouton1 = new TableCell();

                bouton.Text = "Paiement reçu";

                bouton.Attributes["idfacture"] = numfactures;
                bouton.Click += new EventHandler(this.bouton_Click);
                ajoutbouton1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('confirmez votre sélection?');");

                ajoutbouton1.Controls.Add(bouton);
                tRow1.Cells.Add(ajoutbouton1);
                ajoutbouton1.Width = 80;

                ajoutbouton1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
```

```
protected void bouton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button bouton = (Button)sender;
    string idfacture = (string)(bouton.Attributes["idfacture"]);
    string idclient = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost\\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=GYMDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand GetIdFonction = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [dbo].[Finance] SET [status] = 1 WHERE idfacture = " + idfacture + "", con);
    SqlDataReader dr4 = GetIdFonction.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();
    Populerliste(Int32.Parse(idclient));
}
```

Comment: The control is not being repainted.  So y0u are not seeing the new button even though it was created and added to the parent control.  You need to get the parent to repaint.

Comment: the problem is not with the color of the cell actually, the invoice is still marked as "unpaid" in the database because the update query is never executed

Comment: Repaint is not color.  It is the term that refers to updating the control on the screen.  In your case the new button is not being added to the screen because the control was never  updated even though a new button was added to the control.

Comment: can you explain how i can get the parent to repaint?

Comment: Not sure in this case.  Do not have enough info.  When this occurs in a DGV the trick is to set the data source to null and then back to original object like this : datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt;   Maybe in your case the row is off the screen and you need to add a vertical slide bar.

Comment: Side notes: Your SQL has a **dangerous** injection vulnerability, you **must** parameterize it. You also need to dispose the connection, command and reader with `using`. And a reader is unnecessary anyway here, as you are not reading anything, just use `ExecuteScalar` instead

Comment: Are you sure that `bouton_Click` is executed? Debug your code, to find out the problem.